# 404 error displayed when Spring MVC basic web app is run

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I am learning spring MVC. This is a basic code which I found online and trying to run locally. I have added all the dependencies but I am still getting this error:

`The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.`

Here is the code:

This is the landing page which contains the form. On submit, controller will be called.

**index.jsp**

```
<html>  
<body>  
<form action="hello">  
UserName : <input type="text" name="name"/> <br><br>  
Password : <input type="text" name="pass"/> <br><br>   
<input type="submit" name="submit">  
</form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

This is the maven xml which has the spring dependencies.

**pom.xml**

Added the below two dependencies:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->  
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>  
    <version>5.1.1.RELEASE</version>  
</dependency>  

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->  
<dependency>    
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>    
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>    
    <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>    
</dependency>
```

This is the controller. Login is successful when password is 'admin'.

**HelloController.java**

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;  
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;  
import org.springframework.ui.Model;  
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;  

@Controller  
public class HelloController {  

    @RequestMapping("/hello")  
    public String display(HttpServletRequest req,Model m)  
    {  
        //read the provided form data  
        String name=req.getParameter("name");  
        String pass=req.getParameter("pass");  
        if(pass.equals("admin"))  
        {  
            String msg="Hello "+ name;  
            //add a message to the model  
            m.addAttribute("message", msg);  
            return "viewpage";  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            String msg="Sorry "+ name+". You entered an incorrect password";  
            m.addAttribute("message", msg);  
            return "errorpage";  
        }     
    }  
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app>
  <display-name>SpringMVC</display-name>  
   <servlet>    
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>    
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>    
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>      
</servlet>    
<servlet-mapping>    
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>    
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>    
</servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">  

    <!-- Provide support for component scanning -->  
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.javatpoint" />  

    <!--Provide support for conversion, formatting and validation -->  
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>  
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">  
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>  
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>          
     </bean>  
</beans>
```

**viewpage.jsp**

```
<html>  
<body>  
${message}  
</body>  
</html>
```

**errorpage.jsp**

```
<html>  
<body>  
${message}  
<br><br>  
<jsp:include page="/index.jsp"></jsp:include>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: add your screenshot of project folder by WEB-INF expanded. And also give detail of what you were trying to access. "/hello"? Put a Sysout statement in your /hello and check it is printed or not. While asking question give information as much as possible.

Comment: This got fixed now. I deleted the existing package and created a new one and it started working. Not sure what the problem was in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

In your web.xml `<context:component-scan base-package="com.javatpoint" />`,but I don't see `package com.javatpoint;` in your `HelloController`.You need to create a package and put your contorller in it and set it up in web.xml.

Try to create `com.javatpoint` package and put your controller in it.

And you also set `<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>` you need to put your `viewpage.jsp` and `errorpage.jsp` in `/WEB-INF/jsp`. I don't konw whether you create jsp directory in WEB-INF.

Sometimes controller can't find your jsp cause 404.

I create a project using your code,I work well.

Comment: I tried this. But still doesn't work. Any other solution?

Comment: Yes, viewpage.jsp and errorpage.jsp are inside /WEB-INF/jsp. Still not working.

Comment: add your screenshot of project folder by WEB-INF expanded. And also give detail of what you were trying to access. "/hello"? Put a Sysout statement in your /hello and check it is printed or not. While asking question give information as much as possible. Follow completely and given the info

Comment: for 404 error it is required to give complete screenshot of resources and which resource you was trying?